# Comma before "or" or not?

Tags: commas, conjunctions

> "Every student can learn, just not on the same day or the same way." - George Evans

or is it:

> "Every student can learn, just not on the same day, or the same way." - George Evans

Comment: *Not* applies to both parts of the conjunction, so no comma.

Comment: If this is a direct citation then you also have to quote the punctuation as it was written.

Comment: Either one, depending on the author's intended emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

> "Every student can learn, just not on the same day or the same way." – George Evans

From old technology – i.e., a source reference book – it should read "Every student can learn, just not on the same day or the same way." - George Evans

This is correct as '*not* applies to both parts of the conjunction.

However, I see that there are many, many examples picked up by a search have added the comma after day. Who do you trust?

You need to cite the source that you are using and follow its punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

(This old question was bumped today, and I see no very good answers, so I'm providing an answer now. I hope that it's useful.)

The coordinating conjunction "or" connects two noun phrases: "the same day" and "the same way".* Therefore, no comma is necessary. However, the second of two conjuncts may (along with the coordinating conjunction) be surrounded by paired punctuation if it is nonrestrictive. Thus, if the author considered "the same way" to be nonrestrictive, then the comma would be appropriate. (The second comma of the pair is absorbed by the period at the end of the sentence, of course.)

*These noun phrases are objects of the preposition "on", which doesn't really apply to the second. Therefore, I would have written: "Every student can learn, just not on the same day or in the same way."